# Multiple plots sharing one datasource Core Plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

In case of real time data ; I am maintaining a single datasource and multiple plots each having unique identifier and linestyles having unique colour. Inserting data in every plot using the insertDataAtIndex and then in the numberForPlot function returning the appropriate value else returning nil. However only one of the plots gets successfully plotted though it still enters the numberForPlot and symbolForPlot accordingly.Is it possible for multiple plots to share the same datasource or am I missing something here.

Comment: Multiple plots can share a datasource. All of the Core Plot example apps that have more than one plot in a graph do this. With real time data, you may be running into timing issues with data availability. Remember that because of its foundation on Core Animation, everything Core Plot does happens on the main thread. Please provide your code for more help.

Comment: While defining the plots apart from setting an identifier and datasource of the plot to self are there any other properties that need to be set as well ?

Comment: No, and the datasource doesn't have to be the controller that sets up the graph. It can be a separate object if you wish to share it among many graphs. You just have to keep a strong reference to it somewhere (the plots only have a weak reference to prevent retain cycles). Check the data values returned for the plots that aren't working and make sure they're what you expect.

Comment: The data is being returned from the plot functions correctly for all the plots; however only one of the plot is plotted correctly ,the other being empty.

Comment: Also make sure the plot spaces are set up right. Multiple plots can share a plot space or you can have a different one for each plot.

Comment: When adding the plot to the graph it would take the default plot spaces of the graph ,right. ?  So I guess there is no need of defining the plot spaces for the multiple plots.Am I correct here ?

Comment: Yes, `-addPlot:` uses the default plot space.

Comment: And just to be extra sure multiple plots can be added to the same default plot space, right ??  I am using the -addPlot method to add them to the default plot space.

Comment: Yes, as many as you need. You can also mix and match, for example, two plots sharing one plot space and two other plots sharing a second plot space, all in the same graph.

Comment: Thats sound wonderful. Great work sir.